# What Do you Return in Django if Ajax Request is successful?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I have made an Ajax request from a Javascript File to my Python views file in django which is successful but I am unsure what should be my return value.

```
data_from_ajax = request.POST['data']

# do something with the data

return ?
```

I   have tried returning HttpResponse("success") but the Ajax call in javascript still runs the error function. What is the correct return value for a successful ajax request?

Comment: [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice is to return JsonResponse objects with state or code parameter. Your JS script is handling Json parameters and determines what does it mean

```
{success:1,data={id:4}}
```

or

```
{success:0,reason='not_found'}
```

Format is only your deal

About JsonRespose here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects